# Have TouchJSON return mutable objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios, touchjson

I am receiving some json from a web service. I parse this using the TouchJSON library.
I keep the data around for the user to change certain values and then I want to return it to the web service.

The JSON object I get contains NSDictionary Objects within the object, like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": null,
        "created_at": 12332343,
        "object": {
            "name": "Some name",
            "age" : 30 
        },
        "scope": "it stuff",
        "kind_id": 1,
        "valid": true,
        "refering_statement": {
            "id": 95 
        },
        "user": {
            "id": 1 
        } 
    }
]
```

If I want to change values in this dictionary, I can't because the returned objects from TouchJSON are not mutable.

**Is there a way to have have TouchJSON return mutable objects?**

**or is there a way to have Objective C make an NSDictionary and all its children mutable?**

or do I have to just go through every NSDictionary in NSDictionary and copy all data into a mutable copy and then reinsert everything?

Hope someone can help me out on this one:) thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't casting to NSMutableDictionary work for you?

Comment: @Peter Casting is a compile-time construct; it will _not_ change the actual type of an object.

Answer (score 2):

TouchJson has an option to return mutable object rather than normal. (I found it by looking at source code.) Default is to return its "copy", not "mutablecopy".

```
NSError *error = nil;    
jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
CJSONDeserializer *jsondeserializer = [CJSONDeserializer deserializer];
jsondeserializer.scanner.options = kJSONScannerOptions_MutableContainers;
NSMutableDictionary *jsonitems = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[jsondeserializer deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error]];
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, got an error for this line: `jsondeserializer.scanner.options = kJSONScannerOptions_MutableContainers;`

Comment: Minime, thanks for you help! I really should have looked at the source too.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mutable dictionary from a dictionary like this.

(assuming your json parsed dictionary was named jsonDictionary)

```
NSMutableDictionary *userDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:jsonDictionary];
```

Hope that solves it for you.

Comment: Hi Peter and NWCoder. My overall NSDictionary I cast to mutable when parsing is complete. The problem is then the 'user' and 'object' dictionaries inside the overall dictionary are still imutable:( For now I go through each of my json dictionaries, make the outer dict mutable, pull out the inner dicts by key, make a mutable copy of them, delete the old dict and reinsert the new mutable one - terrible workflow, especially when objects change server side. The casting, mutable copy or fast initializer only seem to work on the outer dictionary, which is understandable I guess.