# nsdictionary , nsarray to mutable versions

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

i got an array in every element of this array is a dictionary and every dictionary there are some arrays.

it's like that

[
  {
    [ ]
  },
  {
    [ ]
  }
]

this is the schema i got from a server response.

here's my problem , when i try to change something i got

```
[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
```

so what's the best approach for this ? i need to loop through all items to make them mutable? or is there any other method? because when i call `mutable copy` method , it just convert the outer layer to mutable.

any help will be appreciated..

Comment: You got a server response. Was it JSON? `NSJSONSerialization` class lets you create mutable containers when parsing it.

Comment: yeah its JSON response. could you please give an example?

Comment: It's just a single method call. Please see the documentation for `NSJSONSerialization` class: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

The [TouchJSON library](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON/) has an option to create mutable containers from JSON input.

Check [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7349743/901865) for an example of how to setup TouchJSON's CJSONDeserializer object to create the mutable output.